# BigDump can't import because of constraint of foreign key phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, key

We are trying to get our database imported in our new DataBase environment. 
At first we tried using the phpMyAdmin import function but the database is too big to do that. 
Next, we used BigDump but it also gave us an error of a constraint of the foreign key.
I already took a look what this meant and I saw that the table is unable to drop, replace or update because it can't break the foreign key.

Is there any way to avoid this error?

I have tried this query (I don't have experience using queries):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

But unfortunately this didn't work.

Any more information needed? Feel free to ask!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

When you use my BigDump script uncomment this line in bigdump.php config section in order to disable foreign key checks for each import session:

```
$pre_query[]='SET foreign_key_checks = 0';
```